# How can I convert a text to speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I want my app to read out the message contained in the push notification.
I already searched the internet but I was not able to find some code which was working.

I expect that the text is translated to speech and automatically played.

Comment: You'd use the [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) class. What kind of code did you try and how it failed? There are some easy mistakes to make with Android TTS such as not waiting for the `onInit()` callback to run before trying to speak out something.

Comment: I tryed it with TTS. Now I tryed with Speakerbox and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an easy approach, you can use  [SpeakerBox](https://github.com/mapzen/speakerbox) Library. It's very easy to use.

Just create a new instance

`Speakerbox speakerbox = new Speakerbox(activity);`

Now you are all set. 
If you want to make a speech from the text "Hello World"

Just do this - 

`Speakerbox speakerbox = new Speakerbox(activity);
speakerbox.play("Hello World");`

You will find more details from the mentioned link

The gradle dependency for this library is -

`implementation 'com.mapzen.android:speakerbox:1.4.1'`

Answer (score 0):

you should use **TextToSpeech** within your notification class / service

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);//(Context,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener) 
tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
tts.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

here is a link for more information about **[TextToSpeech](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)**